# Spark error while registering UDF: Schema for type AnyRef is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to register an UDF to sqlContext like this (running spark in local mode)

This is the definition:

```scala
scala> def getStr=udf((s:String) => {val lastS=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1); lastS})
getStr: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction

scala> sqlContext.udf.register("getStr", getStr _)
```

This is supposed to be a simple registration of a function.
Getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type AnyRef is not supported
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:691)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:691)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:119)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
```

... and so on.
Any help please?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly with that UDF ?

Comment: I missed importing org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Answer (score 1):

I missed importing org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ . It's resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

There only two main variants of `UDFRegistration.register` which work with standard (non-aggregate) UDFs:

- one which takes Scala closure (`Function[i]`) where `i` goes from 0 to 22
- one which takes `UDF[i]` which is designed for Java interoperability where `i` goes from 1 to 22

`getStr` is `UserDefinedFunction` so it doesn't match neither of these. To be able to correctly `register` wrapped function you should pass it directly:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("getStr", (s:String) => ...)
```